# cypher query with subpath and exists in redisgraph

Tags: cypher, graph-traversal, redisgraph

I'm evaluating RedisGraph and I'm trying to replicate a result I have in Neo4j.

Graph and query are from [my other question](/q/67007556/3127111), I'm trying to achieve the same result: the path `f1 <- (friend) m2 <- (sibling) b3 <- (coworker) d4` (and none of the `p*` nodes)

Nodes:

```
CREATE (a:temporary {name: 'm2'});
CREATE (a:temporary {name: 'f1'});
CREATE (a:temporary {name: 'b3'});
CREATE (a:temporary {name: 'd4'});

CREATE (a:temporary {name: 'p5'});
CREATE (a:temporary {name: 'p6'});
CREATE (a:temporary {name: 'p7'});

CREATE (a:temporary {name: 'k1'});
CREATE (a:temporary {name: 'k2'});
```

and relations:

```
MATCH (a) WHERE a.name = 'b3' MATCH (b) where b.name = 'm2' CREATE (a)-[:KNOWS {type: 'sibling'}]->(b);
MATCH (a) WHERE a.name = 'm2' MATCH (b) where b.name = 'f1' CREATE (a)-[:KNOWS {type: 'friend'}]->(b);
MATCH (a) WHERE a.name = 'd4' MATCH (b) where b.name = 'b3' CREATE (a)-[:KNOWS {type: 'coworker'}]->(b);

MATCH (a) WHERE a.name = 'p7' MATCH (b) where b.name = 'p6' CREATE (a)-[:KNOWS {type: 'friend'}]->(b);
MATCH (a) WHERE a.name = 'p6' MATCH (b) where b.name = 'p5' CREATE (a)-[:KNOWS {type: 'coworker'}]->(b);

MATCH (a) WHERE a.name = 'k1' MATCH (b) where b.name = 'b3' CREATE (a)-[:HAS]->(b);
MATCH (a) WHERE a.name = 'k1' MATCH (b) where b.name = 'd4' CREATE (a)-[:HAS]->(b);
MATCH (a) WHERE a.name = 'k1' MATCH (b) where b.name = 'm2' CREATE (a)-[:HAS]->(b);
MATCH (a) WHERE a.name = 'k1' MATCH (b) where b.name = 'f1' CREATE (a)-[:HAS]->(b);

MATCH (a) WHERE a.name = 'k2' MATCH (b) where b.name = 'p5' CREATE (a)-[:HAS]->(b);
MATCH (a) WHERE a.name = 'k2' MATCH (b) where b.name = 'p7' CREATE (a)-[:HAS]->(b);
MATCH (a) WHERE a.name = 'k2' MATCH (b) where b.name = 'p6' CREATE (a)-[:HAS]->(b);
```

The original Cypher query:

```
match p=(a:temporary)-[:KNOWS*0..]->(b) 
where not ()-[:KNOWS]->(a) and not (b)-[:KNOWS]->() 
and exists { match (k)-[:HAS]->(a) where k.name='k1' } 
return p
```

Gives the following error, about the subpath in the `EXISTS`:

```
Invalid input '(': expected ':', ',' or '}' line: 1, column: 112, offset: 111 errCtx: ... (b)-[:KNOWS]->() and exists { match (k)-[:HAS]->(a) where k.name='k1' } r... errCtxOffset: 40
```

I've rewritten it like this (with an additional `MATCH` clause: is this equivalent to the above?

```
GRAPH.QUERY test "match p=(a:temporary)-[:KNOWS*0..]->(b) where not ()-[:KNOWS]->(a) and not (b)-[:KNOWS]->() with a, p match (k)-[:HAS]->(a) where k.name='k1'  return p"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's equivalent, rewrite:

```
MATCH (k)-[:HAS]->(a:temporary) WHERE k.name='k1'
MATCH p = (a)-[:KNOWS*0..]->(b) 
WHERE not ()-[:KNOWS]->(a) AND not (b)-[:KNOWS]->() 
RETURN p
```